# How to preserve white spaces when asking questions in this forum?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I need to ask a question in this forum about something else, but to write that post, I need to insert a text based image, like the following,

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~   g**   d *~~
~~   ** *   * ~~
~~   **  ***  ~~
~~   **  d    ~~
~~   **    <  ~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

But the auto formatting has removed all the white spaces, such as those before letter g and d, the ~ symbols should all line up on the right hand side. 
Can someone teach me how to preserve the spaces? so that I can ask what I really wanted to ask in this forum?

Thanks.

Comment: by the way: ***Stack Overflow is NOT a forum***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the text image a code block by putting four spaces at the beginning of each line. You can select some text and use the "code sample" button to add the spaces.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~   g**   d *~~
~~   ** *   * ~~
~~   **  ***  ~~
~~   **  d    ~~
~~   **    <  ~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I did try adding 4 spaces before the lines, but I'll try it again.

Comment: Indeed, it works.  Tusen Takk..

Comment: @ozstudent If not code, better use just `<pre>` tags, code has extra features like prettify which aren't needed in your case.

Comment: You can disable prettify by controlling the [syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). A HTML comment of `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before a code block will tell the prettifier not to do any syntax highlighting on that code block. If you have several code blocks, `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` will affect _all_ following code blocks.